# Configure parallelism on features and scenarios level in the same time - cucumber with Junit5

Tags: junit5, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I checked some similar questions, but did not found an answer for mine. The most similar question was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66815055/run-scenarios-in-a-cucumber-feature-file-in-parallel-one-feature-file-at-a-time), but it's for TestNG. May be somebody faced an issue like me and solved it already?

I use cucumber with junit.

I have several feature files. Each feature file is designed to test one application instance: A.feature, B.feature, C.feature. Each feature file contains one scenario template(outline) with N examples (usually more than 10).
Application instances are independet from each other. And each application instance can process input data in M threads, usually 2. So it does not make sense to run scenarios for particular application instance in more than M (2) threads, because it will lead to flaky tests and unstable execution time.
In the same time running scenarios for one instance (with execution-mode.feature=same_thread) in one thread can take much time.

What do I want to achieve:

- Run feature files in parallel.
- Run scenarios from particular feature file in parallel, but limited to 2 simultaneously running scenarios.
- Overall threads limit should be equal to CPUs count or fixed pool size, let's say 6 (parallel.config.fixed.max-pool-size=6)

Example:

Being executed simultaneusly:

```
A.feature
- scenario 1
- scenario 2

B.feature
- scenario 1
- scenario 2

C.feature
- scenario 1
- scenario 2
```

Waiting in the queue:

```
A.feature
- scenario 3
- scenario 4
...
- scenario 10

B.feature
- scenario 3
- scenario 4
...
- scenario 10

C.feature
- scenario 3
- scenario 4
...
- scenario 10
```

Graphical visualisation for better understanding:

[image]

I suppose that it may be achieved using CustomStrategy:
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine#parallel-execution

> To control properties such as the desired parallelism and maximum
> parallelism, Cucumber supports JUnit 5s
> ParallelExecutionConfigurationStrategy. Cucumber provides two
> implementations: dynamic and fixed that can be set through
> cucumber.execution.parallel.config.strategy. You may also implement a
> custom strategy.

But it could be tricky especially with the fact that I do not understand for now, at what point of time these properties are being set. And could they be changed dynamically (another words based on feature files configuration, not only pom.xml).

My idea was to try using tags on scenario level, something like @feature=A, @feature=B etc to limit parallelism for pool of scenarios. But I'm on the beginning of my journey, so need an advice if it's possible or not.

**UPDATE**
As mentioned in the accepted answer, current implementation of Junit5 does not allow us to do it. Raised a feature request: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/3524

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUnit 5 handles parallel execution for Cucumber. What you are looking to do is currently not possible. While JUnit 5 does support exclusive resources, it does not support resource pools. You would have to ask the JUnit 5 team if they would support this and possibly provide a pull request.

But you could implement this in your own code with something like https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/

Then for each system you're testing against, the pool should contain 2 tokens.

```
@Resource1
Feature: Example 1

  Scenario Outline: Examples

@Resource2
Feature: Example 2

  Scenario Outline: Examples
```

Then before starting the scenario you block and acquire the resources from the pool.

```java
    
    static ObjectPool<?> pool = ...

    @Before
    public void before(Scenario scenario) {
        var tags = scenario.getTags(); // Will contain either @Resource1 or @Resource2.

        // block and acquire a resource from the pool
    }

    @After
    public void after(Scenario scenario) {
        var tags = scenario.getTags();

        // return a resource to the the pool
    }
```

You would have quite a few threads waiting to acquire a resource from the pool, and definitely have more threads then CPUs, which is not pretty, but I do reckon it is manageable.

Note: Haven't used this myself.

Comment: Thanks for your message! Unfortunately I don't feel myself experienced enough in programming to implement this. But will check.

In the same time, can you please clarify how do Test Runner classes (marked with @Suite annotation) use max-pool-size parameter? During my research I saw some examples where guys used several Test Runner classes for parallel run. Is it possible to limit parallelism for specific Test Runner?

Comment: Yes. You can use the `@ConfigurationParameter` (from memory) annotation on the class annotated with `@Suite` to set the parallelism for tests executed by that suite.

Comment: That's great! I'll dig into it and will try to go this way. The only problem will be - different cucumber reports, but I've already found some plugins/projects that can combine multiple reports into one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah right... it won't help much because TestRunners will run sequentially :(